# Best way to structure list that checks against backend

Tags: java, android, optimization, httprequest

Let's say that I have a dynamic list, that expands as more items are scanned (in this case by bluetooth). The idea is to filter out some items in the list based on criteria, for that I've put up an endpoint to check the item against.

Would it be better to:

1. Complete the list, remove the dynamic adding of items, check the whole list against the endpoint, and then show it to the user? i.e `fetch(/filterClaims/:list)`
2. Check each item individually as they are detected (by making a call to the endpoint)? i.e. `fetch(/isclaimed/:id)`
3. Send a list of all the items that need to be filtered out beforehand to the client (in this case a phone) and filter the items as they are detected? i.e `fetch(/claims)`

The amount of devices known to the backend could vary greatly, currently the max is about 100 devices, but this could expand to 1000(s)

(On a side note, if anyone has advice to rephrase the question title, be my guest :))

Comment: I wouldn't say that my method is the best, but in my case i fetch the list initially and store it in my cache. from there, i make request for the list again, then i run the initially stored list against the newly fetched list. I use a method to filter the list for unique values, and if there are unique values present then you can go ahead and notify the user. Then updated the initial list in your cache with the newly fetched list.

Comment: I suppose fetching the list beforehand would be the easiest solution. However this would remove the added benefit of realtime checking as devices come in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As always, it depends. The variant 3 sounds pretty simple and is the least demanding for the server, assuming that the list is short.

If the list doesn't change often, it could be cached in client in order to save bandwidth (the server just says NOT MODIFIED). You could also do incremental updates, but that'd be a premature optimization now.

---

Variant 2 is a sort of a special case of Variant 1 as checking a single item is a special case of checking a list. It makes sense, when the `/claims` list is large or changes a lot. On the server side, I'd only implement checking a list. The client would then check all the items it haven't checked yet (typically just the one scanned most recently).